# How big could a regular star in supergiant/hypergiant phase theoretically get, not counting quasi-stars?

Tags: star, size, red-supergiant, hypergiants

For clarity, I'm not asking about the super-behemoths that are quasi-stars. I'm interested in knowing how large a regular star could theoretically get once it reached supergiant/hypergiant phase, according to our current best models.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_stars ?

Comment: Are you interested in only high mass stars?... i.e., stars with ZAMS mass $\gtrsim 30$ M$_{\odot}$?

Comment: @DaddyKropotkin Not necessarily. Are there medium-mass stars that can get bigger than high-mass stars?

Comment: Bigger in terms of radius? Yes, since the stellar radius also depends on the metallicity and the stage of nuclear evolution that the star is on.